# Error when assigning a spatial reference to a PointGeometry in arcpy

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, pointgeometry

I'm creating a PointGeometry using arcpy:

```
data_path = "E:/Seafile/Seafile/Meine Bibliothek/02_Paper/02_ArcMap/Data/"
point = arcpy.Point(75.9039059275, 35.6928318018)
ptGeometry = arcpy.PointGeometry(point)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(ptGeometry, data_path + "point.shp")
```

So far, so good. However, if I try to add a spatial reference from a prj. file, it gives me this error  `RuntimeError: Object: CreateObject cannot create geometry from inputs` with this code:

```
Albers = arcpy.SpatialReference(data_path + "projection.prj")
point = arcpy.Point(75.9039059275, 35.6928318018)
ptGeometry = arcpy.PointGeometry(inputs=point,
                                 spatial_reference=Albers)
```

I don't get why this would not work. According to the [ESRI website](https://pro.arcgis.com/de/pro-app/arcpy/classes/pointgeometry.htm) I'm following procedure. I don't necessarily need to use the .prj file if there is another way.
So far, I have tried using the `Describe` function to get the coordinate system from another file, but that didn't work, too. I'm looking for a way to assign a spatial reference to this PointGeometry. It is probably very easy but I'm lost.

EDIT:
The error also occurs if I just add `inputs` to the code as the parameter name:

```
ptGeometry = arcpy.PointGeometry(inputs = point)
```

So maybe the coordinate system is not the problem?

If necessary, this is the content of the prj. file:
`PROJCS["Albers_Conic_Equal_Area",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Albers"],PARAMETER["false_easting",0.0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0.0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",87.0],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",25.0],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",50.0],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",37.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]`

Comment: That is not an Albers coordinate, unless you mean to offset <100 meters from the origin.

Comment: No, but it should be an Albers with some custom meridians to match my study area better. The proj-string looks like this: "+proj=aea +lat_1=25 +lat_2=50 +lat_0=37 +lon_0=87 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"

Comment: No, I mean you've specified sub-Angstrom precision on meters values that look suspiciously like degrees.

Comment: Okay, I will look into that, thanks! But maybe you have a solution to my problem? Maybe I can use the proj-string instead?

Comment: Also what's `data_path`, the very string you are using to create the path to the prj file? You are not showing us its value, could all be a silly typo mistake... But if you don't show what the value is then no one can help.

Comment: I'm using this path for all my data in this testing phase, so I don't think that there is a typo, but I've added the string to my question.

Comment: It doesn't look like a modern PE string. Did you assemble it yourself? Esri tools don't accept PROJ (different lineage)

Comment: Honestly, it was assembled by a co-worker some time ago when I was just starting with GIS. I have to admit that I did not check it... But have you seen my edit? The error appears even without specifying a coordinate system.

Comment: I might be misremembering, but I don't think you can use keyword arguments when creating geometry objects, despite what the documentation suggests.  Try using positional arguments only

Comment: @mikewatt: That did it, thanks a lot! Do you want to post this as an answer I can mark as correct lest your comment gets lost at the bottom?

Comment: Sure thing, glad it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite what the documentation suggests (and how Python objects normally work in 99.9% of cases) you can't use keyword arguments when creating geometry objects.  Using positional arguments only should solve the problem

Comment: This issue has been reported and has an internal issue to track it, will be resolved in a future release.